# Aggregate subset values based on string names and calculate % of that value in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a subset. I would like to aggregate the hobby column so that each hobby has its own column name and values. The preferable result would be like step 2. But I will happy as well if you could help me to solve step 1. There are 25 values in total in this subset.   In step 2, I got the percent value by divid its count/ttl counts in the subset.  e.g. the % of playGolf is 2/25=8%. (Note: I have already replaced empty rows with NA and I will keep it as a column.)

```
df:

     country hobby
     <chr>  <chr>
7   Russia  Play Golf
12  Russia  Reading
17  Russia  Reading
20  Russia  Reading
21  Russia  Reading
22  Russia  Cycling
28  Russia  Reading
33  Russia  Reading
35  Russia  Reading
41  Russia  Surfing
48  Russia  NA
61  Russia  Gaming
65  Russia  Reading
70  Russia  Running
74  Russia  Reading
79  Russia  Running
86  Russia  Reading
87  Russia  Gaming
90  Russia  Reading
92  Russia  Prefer not say
95  Russia  Play Golf
96  Russia  Gaming
97  Russia  Reading
98  Russia  Prefer not say
108 Russia  Reading
```

Expected step 1:

```
country    playGolf    Reading    Cycling   Surfing   Gaming  Running     PreNSay     NA

Russia        2         13          1           1       3        2           2         1
```

Expected step 2:

```
country  playGolf(%) Reading(%) Cycling(%) Surfing(%) Gaming(%) Running(%) PreNSay(%) NA(%)
 Russia       8         52        4            4           12       8          8        4
```

After this I am going to combined it with other subsets like this (but I could handle it by myslef):

```
country  playGolf(%) Reading(%) Cycling(%) Surfing(%) Gaming(%) Running(%) PreNSay(%) NA(%)

 Russia       8         52        4            4           12       8          8        4
 Poland       12        24        3            5           10       2          5        1
   ..
 etc...
```

How should I do it? Thank you!

Comment: I guess you need `table(df1)` and `prop.table(table(df1))`

Comment: Thanks @akrun. Could you give me a demo? I tried myself with different approaches, but could not figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `table` to get the frequency count

```
table(df1)
```

-output

```
#  hobby
#country  Cycling Gaming Play Golf Prefer not say Reading Running Surfing
#  Russia       1      3         2              2      13       2       1
```

and to get the percentage use `prop.table`

```
round(100 *prop.table(table(df1)))
```

-output

```
#   hobby
#country  Cycling Gaming Play Golf Prefer not say Reading Running Surfing
#  Russia       4     12         8              8      54       8       4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(country = c("Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", 
"Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", 
"Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", 
"Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia", "Russia"
), hobby = c("Play Golf", "Reading", "Reading", "Reading", "Reading", 
"Cycling", "Reading", "Reading", "Reading", "Surfing", NA, "Gaming", 
"Reading", "Running", "Reading", "Running", "Reading", "Gaming", 
"Reading", "Prefer not say", "Play Golf", "Gaming", "Reading", 
"Prefer not say", "Reading")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("7", 
"12", "17", "20", "21", "22", "28", "33", "35", "41", "48", "61", 
"65", "70", "74", "79", "86", "87", "90", "92", "95", "96", "97", 
"98", "108"))
```

Comment: Thanks@akrun. I will accept the answer when I am allowed. (need to wait some minutes). Thanks again!

Comment: BTW, how I can convert the output as a dataframe @akrun? I need to combine it with other output. I used as.data.frame(round(100 *prop.table(table(df1)))) but it showed in a different view.

Comment: @almo you need `as.data.frame.matrix(`

Comment: @almo if you need the rownames as column `library(dplyr);as.data.frame.matrix(round(100 *prop.table(table(df1)))) %>% rownames_to_column('country')`

Comment: @almo Can you do `install.packages('tibble')` and then `library(tibble)` before doing that step

Comment: Yes, I did @akrun and error was gone. Just let you know. Thank you so much. Perfect answer. Thank you